# How to get the value of below mentioned xml in Python using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using ElemetTree to iterate all the xml tag. Whereas some of my xml contents look like below xml. When iterating the xml getting the `<result1>` tag text as None not "This is the Result of Chrome Browser"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
 <result1 id="val1"><h2>Google Chrome</h2>
 This is the Result of Chrome Browser<p>Google Chrome is a web browser developed by Google, released in 2008. Chrome is the world's 
  most popular web browser today!</p></result1>
</article>
```

Python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
treexml = ET.parse('exam.xml')
for elemintree in treexml.iter():
    print(elemintree.tag,elemintree.text)
```

O/P Getting

```
article
result1 None
h2 Google Chrome
p Google Chrome is a web browser developed by Google, released in 2008. Chrome is the world's 
  most popular web browser today!
```

O/P Wanted

```
h2 Google Chrome
This is the Result of Chrome Browser
p Google Chrome is a web browser developed by Google, released in 2008. Chrome is the world's 
  most popular web browser today!
```

Please Help!!

Comment: "This is the Result of Chrome Browser" is the `tail` of the `<h2>` element. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail

Answer (score 1):

You can search for elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text and elem.tail:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
  <result1 id="val1">
  <h2>Google Chrome</h2>This is the Result of Chrome Browser 
  <p>Google Chrome is a web browser developed by Google, released in 2008. Chrome is the world's most popular web browser today!</p>
  </result1>
</article>
"""
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml_string))

for elem in tree.iter():
    print("TAG: ",elem.tag,'\n', "Text: ", elem.text, '\t\n', "Tail:", elem.tail, '\n\n')
```